# Rails helper_method with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When allowing controller methods as helper in the views, how do you pass an argument?

In my example_controller.rb I have

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :group_exists?

  private
  def group_exists?(gid):
    .. code to check if group exists
  end
end
```

In the view (I use slim), I want to pass an argument

```
- if group_exists?(group.gid)
  | Exists
- else
  | Does not exist
```

However it throws an error saying

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a new helper instead create a method inside the controlle?

Comment: I could, this just seemed simpler as I'm only getting started with rails. Is it that I can't pass arguments by this way?

Comment: Are you sure that the error message is for the line you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy if you really want a helper method, there is already a place defined for it. Just write the same method in `ExampleHelper` class already created for you.

The reason for this is that if you want to debug the helper, you will know where to look very easily. Don't create helpers in controller until your use case specially call for it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw that scaffolding created the ExampleHelper inside helper folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use blocks while using before_filter. It might be useful in helper_method as well, but I am not sure. Try this and please let me know, it worked or not, if not we both will look for other options:

```
helper_method {|x|  x.group_exists?(gid) }
```

Hope it will help. Thanks