# Access helper_method in parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called AdminController with this code:

```
module Admin
  class AdminController < ApplicationController

    helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

    private

    def sort_column(object, column)
      object.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "#{column}"
    end

    def sort_direction
      %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
    end

  end
end
```

And then in another controller called ArticlesController I have this code:

```
module Admin
  class ArticlesController < AdminController

    def index
      @articles = Article
                      .where(status: params[:status].present? ? params[:status] : 1)
                      .order(sort_column(Article, 'publish_date') + ' ' + sort_direction)
    end

  end
end
```

It should be using those helper methods in the parent controller for the sorting, however I get the error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)` for this line: `def sort_column(object, column)`

I should also mention that I use a helper for the sorting:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = (column == sort_column) ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
  end

end
```

Hence why I am using a helper_method.

Comment: ..on what line? Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: define the methods in an module in the app/controllers/concerns/ and include that module in the required controller.

Comment: @DamienRoche Added which line it's breaking on.

Comment: The reason is because you can't use arguments for `helper_method`.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102185/rails-helper-method-with-argument

Comment: @prasad.surase If I move it to a concern, how does my helper access it as well?

Comment: use the 'helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction' after their module has been included in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationHelper#sortable` calls `sort_column` without arguments. `AdminController#sort_column` expects two arguments (`object` and `column`), hence the exception.

To solve that, you can either remove the required arguments or change `#sortable` to use them. What's the best option here I do not know, maybe it is using class attributes instead of arguments to `#sort_column`.